# site.master menu item opens requested page and new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a site.master with a menu (the default one). When I click a menu item I am redirected to the desired page.

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/NewOrder.aspx" Text="New Order" Value="New Orders"></asp:MenuItem>
```

Anyways, what I want is when a client clicks that specific menu item, to navigate to the needed page but also to open a .pdf file (it's a help file) in a new tab, or as a pop-up.
Is that even possible ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write event on menu item click and then do your work in that event :

```
menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);
```

and then

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   

   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page.[GetType](), "", "window.open('Help.pdf');", True)

Comment: So this thing works on my computer. But on any other computer won't open the .pdf file. It will redirect to the needed page, but won't open the .pdf file. I've checked the IE or Chrome settings, and I've added the site in the browser list to accept pop-ups, and again this won't open the .pdf

Comment: PS. You need to remove NavigateUrl="", or this event won't be triggered !